# HTML CSS - Placing one image on top of another

Tags: html, css

I want to place one image on top of another whilst keeping the contents underneath from being shifted up. I know you can use absolute positioning but this shifts everything below behind the image as well. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

I have the below example which I need editing to place the circle on top of the square:

https://jsfiddle.net/Jaron787/2mv98mkp/2/

HTML

```
<div>
  <img src='http://www.clker.com/cliparts/U/D/B/J/j/R/red-square-th.png'>
  <img src='http://www.clker.com/cliparts/G/f/E/Y/v/l/circle-th.png'>
</div>
<div id="lse" class="display">
  <div id="centertbl">
    <table id="tblData" class="TSS">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="4"><b>Table 1</b></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="tblData" class="TSS">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="4"><b>Table 2</b></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 1">
  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 2">
  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 3">
  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 4">

</div>
```

CSS

```
.TSS {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  float: none;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10.6px;
  font-style: normal;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

#centertbl {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following css to the circle:

```
#circle{
 position:relative;
 z-index:1;
left:-100px;
}
```

Edited the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Debabrata89/qdd2z402/

Comment: What would be the easiest way to centre the square in the middle of the div and position the circle over the top

Comment: I have tried center-ing the square but I can't see to get it to center align without the black dot moving onto the next line https://jsfiddle.net/Jaron787/2mv98mkp/4/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Debabrata89/vvx7vach/ .If this is what you want.Basically play with left and top.

Comment: How do i center align the square in the div ?

Answer (score 4):

What you could do is have a div with a background image set in css, then in that div use an `<img />` tag, like below:

HTML:

```
<div class='image-bg'>
  <img src='path/to/image' />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-bg {
/*any other styles*/
background-image: url('relative/path/to/background/image');
```

Answer (score 0):

One method of doing it would be to use negative margins to position one element over the other, with corresponding positive margins on the opposite side(s) in order to maintain the layout, like so:

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;border:0;font-family:sans-serif;margin:0;}
hr{background:#000;border-radius:2px;color:#000;height:2px;margin:20px auto;width:98%;}
div:nth-of-type(2n-1){
  background:#999;
  border-radius:5px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
div:nth-of-type(2n){
  background:#000;
  border-radius:50%;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
}
div:last-of-type{
  margin:-75px 0 75px 25px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<p>Text goes here</p>
<hr>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<p>Text goes here</p>
```

You could also use the [`transform` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) to translate the position of the second div.

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;border:0;font-family:sans-serif;margin:0;}
hr{background:#000;border-radius:2px;color:#000;height:2px;margin:20px auto;width:98%;}
div:nth-of-type(2n-1){
  background:#999;
  border-radius:5px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
div:nth-of-type(2n){
  background:#000;
  border-radius:50%;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
}
div:last-of-type{
  transform:translate(25px,-75px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<p>Text goes here</p>
<hr>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<p>Text goes here</p>
```